# How to get the array consisting of arrays containing the fields from the table row in Django QuerySet API?

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

How to get the array consisting of arrays containing the fields from the table row in Django QuerySet API?

**Db table example:**

id | col1 | col2 | col3

1  |   12 |  123 |  11

2  |   2  |  23  |  2

3 ....

...

**expected result:**

arr = [ [12,123,11], [2,23,2], ... ]

**found solution**:

> > > id = Entry.objects.values_list('id', flat=True).order_by('id')

[1, 2, 3, ...]

> > > col1 = Entry.objects.values_list('col1', flat=True).order_by('id')

[ 12 ,123 ,11 ]

> > > col2 = Entry.objects.values_list('col2', flat=True).order_by('id')

[ 2 , 23, 2]

> > > arr = zip(col1, col2)

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just do

```
Entry.objects.values_list()
```

That's exactly what it does.

Comment: values_list returns tuples. values are inside parenthesis [(1), (2), (3)]
It have to be json serializable and there are lot of them so I'm trying to make it as fastast as possible.
Thanks for response

Comment: No. values_list returns a list of tuples: `[(12, 123, 11), (2, 23, 2), ...]`. That is directly serializable to json by calling `json.dumps(list(entries))`. That's certainly at least thee times faster than your method, which makes *three independent database calls*. Making individual db calls will definitely be much much slower. Don't do it.

Answer (score 0):

Summarize

If you want to serialize into json each row from table

example:

arr = [ [col1, col2, col3], [col1, col2, col3], [col1, col2, col3] ]

use

Entry.objects.values_list()

and

json.dumps(list(entries))